# How i can pass argument in OnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, shell

In my shell script I am setting command on OnOutOfMemoryError, so when i pass only
Cloud_Metrix.sh then it's working but when i pass Cloud_Metrix.sh $runtime_params it's not working i want to pass the argument

```
if [[ $SERVICE_NAME == "abc" ]]; 
then
  runtime_params="hello"
  JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"Cloud_Metrix.sh $runtime_params\""
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set the JAVA_OPTS environment variable to specify the behavior when an OutOfMemoryError occurs in the Java Virtual Machine. However, there might be an issue with the way you are passing the arguments in the JAVA_OPTS variable.

When you use the JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="Cloud_Metrix.sh $runtime_params"" line, it is essential to make sure that the $runtime_params variable is properly expanded when it is set. To do this, you can use single quotes instead of double quotes around the entire string:

---

```
bash

if [[ $SERVICE_NAME == "abc" ]]; 
then
  runtime_params="hello"
  JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='Cloud_Metrix.sh $runtime_params'"
fi
```

---

Using single quotes will prevent the immediate expansion of $runtime_params, so it will be evaluated later when the JAVA_OPTS variable is used. Also, there's no need to escape the double quotes around Cloud_Metrix.sh $runtime_params in this context.

Now, when you pass the JAVA_OPTS to the Java process, it should correctly include the OnOutOfMemoryError behavior with the Cloud_Metrix.sh script and the runtime_params argument.

Comment: I tried like runtime_params="hello"
     JAVA_OPTS+=" -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='Cloud_Metrix.sh $runtime_params'" still same.  I have print the JAVA_OPTS value as well it's like -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=128m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='Cloud_Metrix.sh hello'

Comment: and when i print JAVA_OPTS then i am getting  value like this '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='\''Cloud_Metrix.sh' 'hello'\''' looks like script is changing  this space.   looks like it's passing as two parameter